# EC2 OpenVPN server within VPC access with ALB/ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I currently have a private VPC with an OpenVPN server on an EC2 within it. Clients connect to the OVPN server and I can ping the connected clients via the server. Now I'd like to setup an ALB/ELB that would allow access to the clients on the OVPN server. Is that possible, I think I need a bridge?

I was thinking about perhaps installing nginx on the OVPN server and reverse proxying to the clients, but I feel like there's a more AWS way of going about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before messing with the ALB check the costs, they can start to grow sooner than you might think. However, the ALB is for load balancing the traffic from outside to your AWS component (EC2, Beanstalk, etc...) and not the opposite.

Comment: Thanks, I’ve figured it out I’m just using Nginx and doing proxy_pass